# Is it mandatory to use $scope.$apply for non-angular event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-apply

Is it a good practice to always update scope variable(s) using $scope.$apply when the control returns from a non-angular event?

I have a use case where same method is used by both angular and non-angular event and I want to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

You do need to use it if you are going to run code in a new turn. And only if that turn isn’t being created from a method in the AngularJS library. Inside that new turn, you should wrap your code in `$scope.$apply().`  Take a look at this [link](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html).